# How to use Bootstrap 4's "site\docs\4.4\examples" Folder contents using Jekyll on GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, css, github, bootstrap-4, github-pages

In the examples folder of **Bootstrap 4**, I was wondering on how to use and view its contents as everytime I open an **index.html** file to my browser it looks like this:

[image: no css output]

I know I have to use **Jekyll** for this but how am I supposed to use it to view the documents on my **GitHub** account?

As this is my first encounter with **Jekyll**, I don't really know the function of the codes like the ones that could be found at the top of the **HTML** document:

```html
---
layout: examples
title: Album example
extra_css: "album.css"
---

<header>
  <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        ...
```

Can anyone help me and also explain what these things do?

Comment: use bootstrap4 cdn in template

Comment: @Ankit I just have to add it on the HTML document?

Comment: kindly provide you whole html document